# SQL Developer Copy data from Materialized View of one connection to a table of another connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using SQL Developer, I am trying to copy the data from a Materialized View on one database/connection to a table (of the same name) on another database/connection.

The name and columns of the MV and table are exactly the same.

I tried to use the database copy tool on SQL Developer but I ran into errors. I am not very sure which options I should check/uncheck.

I am using:
Oracle 19c

SQL Developer version: 21.4.3.063 Build: 063.0100

Comment: What is the error text?

Comment: I can't remember what the errors were but I was trying different options. But if I just choose copy data, I will get "Skipping MV_USERS" (MV_USERS is the name of my MV/table)